# Laravel 9. Blade components

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade

is it possible to pass collections to a component like this:

```
class projectAccordion extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $projects = Project::with('subservice', 'partner')->orderByDesc('id')->limit(4)->get();
        return view('components.front.project-accordion', compact('projects'));
    }
}
```

the component itself looks like this:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
        <div class="info-list-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 project-info-list">
                    <div class="info-list-title">
                        <div class="date">
                            <span>{{ date('d F, Y', strtotime($project->created_at)) }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <h4>
                            {{ $project->title }}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 project-info-list">
                    <div class="info-list-txt">
                        <p>
                            {{ $truncated = Str::of($project->descr)->limit(100) }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 project-info-list">
                    <div class="info-list-img">
                        <img src="{{ $project->partner->file_url }}" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

this is how i call the component in homeage.blade.php

```
<x-front.project-accordion></x-front.project-accordion>
```

This method does not work on hosting, but everything works on the local version.Is this the right approach?

[image]

Comment: it is possible to send a collection to blade, what was the problem on hosting, did you get any error message ? small suggestion , for date you can use $project->created_at->format('d F, Y') cause laravel read it as carbon datetime , and another question , is $project->partner has only single value and is it always available or optional ?

Comment: call comment in homepage.blade.php
<x-front.project-accordion></x-front.project-accordion>

Comment: i did not see any comment inside this component project-accordion , can you update your code ? thanks

Comment: sorry, I wanted to write a component, not a comment